# Graphhopper gpx file- checking route tag

Tags: routes, openstreetmap, graphhopper

The situation looks following: We have a GPX file (which is basicaly XML) from routing service Graphopper that base on OpenStreetMaps. Each route in this maps .osm( same kinda XML) files is tagged eg. highway =primary , highway=motorway ... What I would like to do is to check for arbitrary point (latitude,longitude) from my GPX file generated from routing service to what kind of route it belongs to, I mean if its primary, motorway etc. Is there already a built in method for things like that in some API or something? Or is it gonna be hard to do on my own?
Regards

Comment: What is your use case? And you could use overpass turbo but I fear there are just too many points per route that it will take too long and you'll also not comply to their free usage policy :)

Comment: Suppose I have a random GPS position. I need to determine wheter it's on high speed road, residentional or other type ( That point will always be on some road with +/- 10 meters accuracy caused of GPS margin error). Every single road represtented as polyline consists of up to 1000 points ( Usually more less than that). They connect in a route in GPX.  The most convenient would be to have in GPX the same tag about every road as that one used in .osm files, but routing services gives nothing similiar.

Comment: GraphHopper could include this but I fear this is too specific to be done in a general way as GraphHopper can load also from other data sets

Comment: Ok, I have found some useful program and now I can have a spreadsheet with road IDs and names from a certain region generated from .osm file, with information what kind of road is it. Now what remains is to check  what road (ID or name only) the GPS position belongs to. Street names are given in the GPX from GraphHopper but is kinda weird to parse...

Comment: what is weird about them?